# Make app like Photo Library swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app like Photo Library in iphone

But I do not know what view is used to show images: UITableView or UIPickerView or UICollectionView.

With Table View: it scroll too fast - How to "stop at next cell when I slide it?"

With Picker View: the images are blurred at top and bottom, how to remove its?

Or Collection View?

Comment: Or collection view?

Comment: What have you tried? Any code you can give to help us? Please, be a bit more specific about the issue you have. Thanks.

Comment: Search Github. There are many existing libraries there for simulating the photo library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView for it.

Check this link for more details

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started